# How can I use DateTime.Now.Year as default for optional parameters

Tags: c#, class, optional-parameters

Can you tell my how can I workaround the error

> Default parameter value must be a compile-time constant"

I know the problem and already saw solutions for methods here on Stack Overflow, but I don't get how to solve this problem for classes.

```
public class member
{
    public string name { get; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public int entryYear;
    static int memberNbr;

    public member (string _name, int _entryyear = DateTime.Now.Year, string _email = "")
    {
        name = _name;
        entryyear = _entryyear;
        email = _email;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could make it `int?`, default it to `null` and then if it comes in as `null`, set the field to the non-constant you wanted.

Comment: If you *really* have to do it that way, make your method signature be `public member (string _name, int _entryyear = default(int), string _email = "")` - `_entryyear` will default to `default(int)` (i.e. `0`), then inside the method you can do  `entryYear = _entryyear == default(int) ? DateTime.Now.Year : _entryyear;`. The provided answers are a much cleaner way to go about this.

Comment: Thanks you for the solution, but I'm in my first semester of my computer science studies and not allowed to use int?

Comment: You really can't use int?. That sounds like a very odd method of teaching! What happens if you do?

Comment: It just wasn't topic of the lecture yet, so my fellow students, which correct this exercise wouldn't understand it and deduct points.

Comment: Default values are evaluated at compile-time, so can't be code.  You only need a constant that makes it obvious that the client code did not pass the argument, -1 is a good choice for a year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of having it be an optional parameter, what about a different constructor overload? And within the 2nd constructor, don't take entryYear as a parameter, but instead initialize it within the constructor body?

And while we're at it, let's use proper C# conventions, such as property names being PascalCase and constructor parameters being camelCased. And not using abbreviations for property names, and don't make MemberNumber static when it clearly belongs to a single instance.

```
public class Member
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public string Email { get; }

    public int EntryYear { get; }

    public int MemberNumber {get; }

    public Member(string name, int entryYear, string email = "")
    {
        Mame = Name;
        EntryYear = entryYear;
        Email = email;
    }

    public Member(string name, string email = "")
    {
        Mame = Name;
        EntryYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
        Email = email;
    }
}
```

You didn't ask about it, but it doesn't really make sense to initialize the email with an empty string. Probably better to have it default to null.

Comment: Thank you that's a comfortable solution which I easily understand. I made memberNbr static because later it should increase itself by one for every object. Didn't implented this yet.

Comment: @D.Brown The point being to assign each user a unique MemberNumber? By having it static, they will all share the same MemberNumber.

Comment: Yeah now I see, but how do you assign each member a unique number? When I use static everyone gets the figure of the total number of members (i. e. 8 There are 8 members, evreyone gets the number 8). And when it is not static erveryone gets the number 1.

Comment: @D.Brown You'll need to keep track of the number separately. If you use SQL Server to store your data, it can automatically assign sequential numbers.

Comment: No SQL, but I got the solution now. I just need a static counter and a ID, which is not static. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your static counter is going to reset if you stop and start the app.

Answer (score 3):

Given that it's not possible to have a non-constant value as a default parameter, you'll have to use overloads:

```
public class Member
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int EntryYear { get; set; }

    private int _memberNumber;

    public Member(string name) : this(name, DateTime.Now.Year, "")
    { }

    public Member(string name, int year) : this(name, year, "")
    { }

    public Member(string name, string email) : this(name, DateTime.Now.Year, email)
    { }

    public Member(string name, int entryYear, string email)
    {
        Name = name;
        EntryYear = entryYear;
        Email = email;
    }
}
```

Notice that I've fixed casing for you, you should learn c# conventions as early as possible. Also, `_memberNumber` shouldn't be static, unless all members have the same number, which would be kinda weird.

Regarding the MemberNumber, you may want something basic like this:

```
public static class MemberHelpers
{
    // you would have to load this if the data is persisted in some way
    private static int _lastMemberNumber;

    public static int GetNewMemberNumber()
    {
        return _lastMemberNumber++;
    }
}

public Member(string name, int entryYear, string email)
{
    Name = name;
    EntryYear = entryYear;
    Email = email;

    _memberNumber = MemberHelpers.GetNewMemberNumber();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Btw I made memberNbr static because later it should increase itself by one for every object. Didn't implented this yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with second constructor..

```
public class member
            {
                public string name { get; }
                public string email { get; set; }
                public int entryYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
                static int memberNbr;

                public member(string _name, string _email = "")
                {
                    name = _name;
                    email = _email;
                }                
                public member(string _name, int _entryyear , string _email = "")
                {
                    name = _name;
                    entryYear = _entryyear;
                    email = _email;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Typically when overloading constuctors you'd just call the other one with the value like `public member(string _name, string _email = "") : this(_name, DateTime.Now.Year, _email)`

Comment: @juharr: Minor quibble. You don't *overload* constructors, you create multiple constructors.

Comment: @Flydog57 Funny how two other answers call it overloading too.

Comment: Hence "minor quibble". Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors *"Classes and structs can also define multiple constructors, and neither is required to define a default constructor."*

Answer (score 0):

A year can't sensibly be eg. int.MinValue. So you could theoretically set the default parameter to int.MinValue, and interpret that as DateTime.Now.Year.

However, code should always be optimised for reading, and that definitely doesn't make it obvious what's going on. So I definitely would not advise doing this in a public API. In a private method though it could be ok, but make sure you document what's going on.

This could also cause issues with testing, if you use edge cases such as int.MinValue in your tests.

As such, I would definitely go for a nullable int instead and use a default parameter of null to mean DateTime.Now.Year.

Even then, I still would advise against that in a public API, and go for method overloads instead. However for non public code, it can be nicer to reduce clutter by having fewer methods, and using default parameter.